# Batch or Python script to append files in subfolders

Tags: python, r, vba, append, subdirectory

I want to append a 52 specific files (Order.xls) from different subfolders. This is the structure of my folder:

```
Year_2018
----Week1
    --order.xls
----Week2
    --order.xls
----Week3
    --order.xls
   |
   |
   |
----week52
    --order.xls
```

I already tried to append the file using this code below but apparently it override the data

```
 for /R %f in (orders.xls) do type "%f" >> C:\Users\Desktop\output.xls
```

I would like to have a unique file that is appending all the order.xls from the different weekly folders.
You support would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: `XLS` files are binary files.  You cannot combine them into one file like that.  You would have to write a VBA script that runs within Excel.  Search SO and the Internet.  I know this question has been answered in the past.

Comment: What if i change the extension from xls to csv?

Comment: Changing a file extension doesn't magically make it a different file format.  If the files were created and saved as XLS files, they are binary files.  Renaming the file with a different extension does not magically change the file format to ASCII text.

Comment: You mean you want to merge several XLS files into one?

Comment: Yes that what i want to do

Comment: Then you need to write VBA to copy all the worksheets into a single new workbook, or to copy the data from each sheet and put it into a single sheet, or use a Python Excel library to achieve the same.

Comment: Why would you remove Excel from the question title and remove the Excel tag? That is a critical component of your question.  If anything you need to remove `Batch` from your question title.